# Is it mandatory to install Java for the correct operation of Ubuntu / Xubuntu etc?

Tags: xubuntu, java

Hi, sorry for the lack of knowledge, maybe this is a stupid question. Is it necessary to install java after installing Ubuntu for the correct operation of the system? I mean for a standard user who only uses the pc for some tricks and basic things.

Comment: No, although I don't know what is "a standard user who only uses the pc for some tricks and basic things". Can you state it less vaguely?

Comment: By standard user I meant someone who only uses a PC to watch videos, listen to music, documents, etc. Although it may not be the ideal word. I like the command line and fiddle with settings to put the system as I please. I love Linux but I don't have much time to spend on the PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those "tricks" don't involve Java applications, no.

`python` is rather important in Ubuntu nowadays, but you can expect to have all applications and dependencies necessary for the OS' operation preinstalled.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not, and certainly not after a full install. I used Ubuntu for the past year without a need for Java until recently when I needed to install it for a Java programming course. Aside from that it never came up.

There are applications in the Software Centre that say they use Java, but I would assume if you install them the required Java libraries would be installed as dependancies.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. 